# Как удалить строки из таблицы так, чтобы счетчик столбца AUTO_INCREMENT "откатился" назад?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users со столбцами **login**, **password** и автоинкрементным столбцом **id**.

Допустим в таблице есть уже 5 пользователей. Я хочу удалить три последних пользователя: 3, 4, 5

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id > 2;
```

Но нужно сделать так, чтобы после удаления при занесении нового пользователя id у него был не 6, а 3.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Не трогать Primary key и создать отдельный столбец, в котором и вести необходимый Вам подсчет. С ним же и производить любые операции, какие только душе угодны.